# Bash Parameter Substitution: command line vs. script

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

I am practicing with [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) in bash.

I wrote the following dummy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext.0.random.ext"
var2="/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext.0.ext"

pattern='.[0-9]?(.random).ext'

echo "${pattern}"
echo "${var1/${pattern}/}"
echo "${var2/${pattern}/}"
```

Basically, the pattern is meant to strip off the last part of the file
name.

---

Executing the dummy script results in:

```
~$ ./dummy.sh 
.[0-9]?(.random).ext
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext.0.random.ext
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext.0.ext
```

whereas `eval`ing the script's contents or, equivalently, the direct input of that sequence of commands in the interactive shell, results in:

```
~$ eval "$(cat dummy.sh)"
.[0-9]?(.random).ext
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext
```

The pattern `'.[0-9]*.ext'` works, so the issue clearly is confined to the sub-string `'?(.random)'`. The issue could be with `?`, since it is a reserved character in the context of parameter substitution. However, if that were the issue, I would expect the pattern to either fail or succeed the same in both cases.

Where's the probably obvious pitfall?

Comment: FYI, to "strip off the last part of" a string, use `${parameter%pattern}` or `${parameter%%pattern}` to match the shortest or the longest  matching  pattern. `${parameter/pattern/string}`is used for pattern  substitution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem may be that the `extglob` shell option is set in the interactive shell, but not in the script shell.

```
$ shopt -u extglob
$ echo "${var1/${pattern}/}"
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext.0.random.ext
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${var1/${pattern}/}"
/some/path/to/file/the_file.arbitrary.n.ext
```

So you can try putting `shopt -s extglob` right after the shebang line in the script.

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized....
>   Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> `?(PATTERN-LIST)`
>       Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns.